# JMeter- Scripting through Azure AD OAuth 2.0

Tags: azure, oauth, jmeter

JMeter documentation stipulates using HTTP Header Managers with Authorization: Bearer Tokens to get past OAUTH 2.0. But if the Azure site does not accept Bearer Tokens (aside from API calls) what is the best practices to send OAUTH 2.0 information through JMeter?

Are there other considerations to take care of, such as the nature of JMeter running through a proxy and therefore the signing of tokens differs from that of the host site? Is it possible to grab all the data with Regex Extractors from the POST call? If so, what is the relevant data that needs to be grabbed per user?